# Quasi-differencing of irregular AR(1) process

Tags: regression, time-series, mathematical-statistics, generalized-least-squares

Suppose $\delta_{jt} = x'_{jt}\beta + \xi_{jt}$ where $\xi_{jt}$ is an AR(1) process, i.e. $\xi_{jt} = \rho \xi_{jt-1} + \eta_{jt}$. I am assuming that $\text{Cov}(x_{jt}, \eta_{jt}) = 0$.

I know $\rho$, $\delta_{jt}$ and $x_{jt}$. Neither $\xi_{jt}$ nor $\eta_{jt}$ are observable. I want to estimate $\beta$. To do this, I can quasi-difference,
$$
\delta_{jt} - \rho\delta_{jt-1} = (x'_{jt} - \rho x'_{jt-1})\beta + (\xi_{jt} - \rho\xi_{jt-1}) = (x'_{jt} - \rho x'_{jt-1})\beta + \eta_{jt}
$$
and then run an OLS regression to estimate $\beta$ which is valid by the covariance assumption earlier.

Now, suppose that $\xi_{jt}$ is an **irregular** AR(1) process. ie

$$
\xi_{jt} = \begin{cases}
\rho \xi_{jt-1} + \eta_{jt} & \text{for certain (known) values of $t$} \\
\xi_{jt-1} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I want to estimate $\beta$ again. I was thinking of calculating quasi-differences with respect to when $\xi_{jt}$ last changed and then running GLS. Or is there a better (more efficient) way?

Example: Suppose that $\xi_{j2} = \rho\xi_{j1} + \eta_{j1} $ and $\xi_{j3} = \xi_{j2}$. Then I could quasi-difference both periods 3 and 2 with respect to period 1,
$$
\begin{gather}
\delta_{j2} - \rho \delta_{j1} = (x'_{j2} - \rho x'_{j1})\beta + \eta_{j1} \\
\delta_{j3} - \rho \delta_{j1} = (x'_{j3} - \rho x'_{j1})\beta + \eta_{j1}
\end{gather}
$$
and estimate using GLS as I know the structure of the covariance matrix.

Comment: Those covariance assumptions don't look right to me but, this appears to be a linear Gaussian state space model. Is there some reason why you don't just use the Kalman filter?

Comment: I've fixed the typo in the covariance assumption